# pika connection times out during execution of long task (3+ minutes)

Tags: python, rabbitmq, task, pika

I have a process in which I need to assign long running tasks amongst a pool of workers, in python. So far I have been using RabbitMQ to queue the tasks (input is a nodejs frontend); a python worker subscribes to the queue, obtains a task and executes it. Each task takes several minutes minimum.

After an update this process started breaking, and I eventually discovered this was due to RabbitMQ version 3.6.10 having changed the way it handles timeouts. I now believe I need to rethink my method of assigning tasks, but I want to make sure I do it the right way.

Until now I only had one worker (the task is to control a sequence of actions in a VM - I couldn't afford a new Windows license for a while, so until recently I had no practical way of testing parallel task execution); I suspect if I'd had two before I would have noticed this sooner. The worker attaches to a VM using libvirt to control it. The way my code is written currently implies that I would run one instance of the script per VM that I wish to control.

I suspect that part of my problem is the use of BlockingConnection - I think I need a way for the worker to disconnect from the queue when it has received and validated a task (this part takes less than 1 sec), then reconnect once it has completed the actions, but I haven't figured out how to do this yet. Is this correct? If so, how should I do this, and if not, what should I do instead?

One other idea I've had is that instead of running a script per VM I could have a global control script that on receiving a task would spin off a thread which would handle the task. This would solve the problem of the connection timing out during task execution, but the timeout would just have moved to a different stage: I would potentially receive tasks while there were no idle VMs, and I would have to come up with a way to make the script await an available VM without breaking the RabbitMQ connection.

My current code can be seen here:

https://github.com/scherma/antfarm/blob/master/src/runmanager/runmanager.py#L342

Any thoughts folks?

Comment: "RabbitMQ version 3.6.10 having changed the way it handles timeouts" - as far as I know, this is not true (I'm on the RabbitMQ core team). What version of Pika? You don't provide any details about the "timeout" or what exactly is breaking in your process. Do you have Pika stack traces or entries from your application's error logging? Have you run a Wireshark packet capture (port 5672) to see exactly what is going on? Any interesting entries in RabbitMQ's log? Consider posting this to `rabbitmq-users` as more people read that than Stack Overflow to help RabbitMQ users.

Comment: Slightly off wording possibly, I found a thread indicating that this version dropped the timeout interval from 10 minutes to one minute. However, I have since discovered that the problem may be that I should not be using the pika BlockingConnection, but instead the AsyncIO method (for which I must update to python3). I'm currently investigating that avenue instead.